# Sharing contact on Android 7.0

Tags: android, share, contacts, android-7.0-nougat

Problem is when I try to share contact on Android 7.0, my application getting crash.

```
   final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

            cursor = resolver.query(contactsUri, null, null, null, null);
            String name = "";
            String contactLookupKey = "";
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contactLookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            }

            name = name.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "_");
            name = name + "_" + CONTACT_PREFIX;
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI,
                    contactLookupKey);

            File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "contacts");
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                storageDir.mkdir();
            }
            File vCardFile = File.createTempFile(name, ".vcf", storageDir);

            if (!vCardFile.exists()) {
                vCardFile.createNewFile();
            }
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(vCardFile);

            AssetFileDescriptor
                    fd = resolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            fis = fd.createInputStream();

            final byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];

fd.getDeclaredLength() - return "-1" and app crash?
```

What could be a problem?

Comment: works with 
final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
so, that is not problem becuse when I open fd object in debuger, his lenght is -1... and contact is empty, so problem is in .openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r")

Answer (score 1):

Solution /
instead:

```
final byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
```

use:

```
byte[] buf;

if (fd.getDeclaredLength() != AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH) {
    buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
} else {
    buf = new byte[fis.available()];
}
fis.read(buf);
```